# How to validate a discriminator array using Joi, Mongoose & Hapi?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, joi

Let's say we have a model set up like this:

```js
const model = new mongoose.Schema({
  foo: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  discriminatorArray: [new mongoose.Schema({
    bar: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
    }
  }, {
    discriminatorKey: 'baz',
    _id: false,
  })],
});

const docArray = model.path('discriminatorArray');

docArray.discriminator('discriminatorValue1', anotherModel1);
docArray.discriminator('discriminatorValue2', anotherModel2);

mongoose.model('Model', model);
```

Which results in:

```js
{
  "foo": "someValue",
  "discriminatorArray": [{
    "bar": "someValue",
    "baz": "discriminatorValue1",
    "anotherModel1Prop": "someValue"
  }, {
    "bar": "someValue",
    "baz": "discriminatorValue2",
    "anotherModel2Prop": "someValue"
  }]
}
```

How would you validate the array correctly using Joi?

Boilerplate:

```js
Joi.validate(payload, Joi.object({
  foo: Joi
    .string()
    .required(),
  discriminatorArray: Joi
    .array()
    .items(Joi.object({
      bar: Joi
        .string()
        .optional(),
      baz: Joi
        .string()
        .valid(['discriminatorValue1', 'discriminatorValue2'])
        .required(),
    }))
    .required(),
}));
```

The only 2 ways I can get this working is:

1. Include all possible keys for anotherModel1 & anotherModel2, then use

```js
Joi.when('baz', {
  is: 'discriminatorValue1',
  then: Joi.string(),
  otherwise: Joi.forbidden(),
})
```

However the different models share some of the same keys, this ends up messy and it doesn't make sense to me to include all keys, but instead to create a separate schema for the different discriminators and use something like:

```
const items = Joi.object().keys({
  bar: Joi
    .string()
    .optional(),
  baz: Joi
    .string()
    .valid(['discriminatorValue1', 'discriminatorValue2'])
    .required(),
});

const schema = Joi.object({
  foo: Joi
    .string()
    .required(),
  discriminatorArray: Joi
    .array()
    .items(items.when('baz', {
      is: 'discriminatorValue1',
      then: object.keys(anotherSchema1),
    }).when('baz', {
      is: 'discriminatorValue2',
      then: object.keys(anotherSchema2),
    })),
});
```

2. Change the model to look like this:

```js
{
  "foo": "someValue",
  "someArray": [{
    "baz": "discriminatorValue1",
    "discriminatorArray": [{
      "anotherModel1Prop": "someValue"
    }]
  }, {
    "baz": "discriminatorValue2",
    "discriminatorArray": [{
      "anotherModel2Prop": "someValue"
    }]
  }]
}
```

So that the Joi validation would look something like this (untested):

```js
Joi.validate(payload, Joi.object({
  foo: Joi
    .string()
    .required(),
  someArray: Joi
    .array()
    .items(Joi.object({
      baz: Joi
        .string()
        .valid(['discriminatorValue1', 'discriminatorValue2'])
        .required(),
      discriminatorArray: Joi
        .array()
        .when('baz', {
          is: 'discriminatorValue1',
          then: Joi
            .array()
            .items(Joi.object({
              anotherModel1Prop: Joi
                .string()
                .required(),
            })),
        })
        .when('baz', {
          is: 'discriminatorValue2',
          then: Joi
            .array()
            .items(Joi.object({
              anotherModel2Prop: Joi
                .string()
                .required(),
            })),
        }),
    }))
    .required(),
}));
```

Any thoughts and solutions on this would be great.

**Resources:**

- [Mongoose Discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)
- [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md)

Answer (score 0):

I settled for including all possible keys and writing some logic to build the schema based on config files.

Config arrays look like this:

```
{
  key: 'anotherModel1Key',
  required: true,
}
```

Then I wrote something like this:

```
const items = {
  bar: Joi
    .string()
    .optional(),
  baz: Joi
    .string()
    .valid(['discriminatorValue1', 'discriminatorValue2'])
    .required(),
};

// function to add additional keys from configs which ends with

items[key] = Joi.when('baz', {
  is: Joi.only(arrayOfBazValuesIdentifyingWhenThisKeyIsAllowed),
  then: Joi.string().trim()[required](),
  otherwise: Joi.forbidden(),
});
```

Followed by returning the schema:

```
return Joi.validate(payload, Joi.object({
  foo: Joi
    .string()
    .required(),
  discriminatorArray: Joi
    .array()
    .items(items)
    .required(),
}));
```